# What is the effect of aspect ratio on cruise velocity?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, cruise

Does the Aspect ratio affect the Maximum cruise velocity please?

I was thinking it wouldn’t as Aspect ratio= b^2/S.

If I wanted to go quicker I could just increase my span and decrease S?

Comment: The key is total drag.  At some point extra form drag and extra weight from structural strength requirements cancel reduction in induced drag.  Interesting that undersea creatures swimming in greater density water do not sport very high AR.

Comment: You should explain what variables you are using.  So, is "b" span, and "S" area?

Comment: So basically it seems you are suggesting to cruise as fast as possible, we should make the aspect ratio as high as possible, and to scale down the wing (reduce area) as needed to allow us to operate at an optimal angle-of-attack during high-speed cruising flight. (Obviously a high aspect-ratio wing is a poor choice for operating at a *low* angle-of-attack.)  Well, that all seems plausible --